# GNU awk ERRNO not set on command failure

Tags: awk, gawk

I was trying run a few commands using `getline()` function of GNU `awk` and print the error number (`errno`) value returned. But for simple failure cases of non existent directory/file the variable doesn't seem to be populated.

```
awk 'BEGIN {
        cmd = "ls -lrth /non/existing/path"
        while ( ( cmd | getline result ) > 0 ) {
            print result
        }
        close(cmd); print ENVIRON["ERRNO"]
}'
```

When the above puts out the error string from `ls`, the `print` statement does not produce a valid error number. I've also tried from the [man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Auto_002dset.html) to use `PROCINFO["errno"]` and `PROCINFO["ERRNO"]` which didn't work. I also tried printing it before closing the file descriptor which also didn't work. Is it wrong to expect `ENOENT` in this case?

Comment: ERRNO is just a gawk built-in string variable. It would only be in the ENVIRON array if it was an exported shell variable. Further, the ENVIRON array is only created when the awk process initialises: it won't get new entries added to it, and the values of the initial entries won't be updated if the shell variables change.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can not get the error number using `getline`. In your command, the output is from `ls`, not `print result`.

In form `cmd | getline result`, `cmd` is run, then its output is piped to `getline`. It returns `1` if got output, `0` if EOF, `-1` on failure. The problem is that failure is from running `getline` itself, not the return code of `cmd`. Example:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
while ( ( getline result < "/etc/shadow") > 0 ) {
            print result
        }
        print "XXX: ", ERRNO
}'
XXX:  Permission denied
```

You will see that `/etc/shadow` can not be read, so `getline` fails to run and reports the error in `ERRNO` variable.

---

Note that GNU awk will return the `cmd` status if not in posix mode, so you can do:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
    cmd = "ls -lrth /non/existing/path"
    while ( ( cmd | getline result ) > 0 ) {
        print result
    }
    status=close(cmd);
    if (status != 0) {
        code=and(rshift(status, 8),0xFF)
        printf("Exit status: %d, exit code: %d\n", status, code)
    }
}'
ls: cannot access '/non/existing/path': No such file or directory
Exit status: 512, exit code: 2
```

In POSIX mode, You won't get the exit status:

```
POSXILY_CORRECT=1 awk 'BEGIN {
    cmd = "ls -lrth /non/existing/path"
    while ( ( cmd | getline result ) > 0 ) {
        print result
    }
    status=close(cmd);
    if (status != 0) {
        code=and(rshift(status, 8),0xFF)
        printf("Exit status: %d, exit code: %d\n", status, code)
    }
}'
ls: cannot access '/non/existing/path': No such file or directory
```

Comment: So the `cmd|getline result` not a proper way to catch the error number? How would it need to be used if I want to catch the error number, which I think in this case should be `2`? (`ENOENT`)

Comment: @Inian Use system instead. In this case, you just have to check `getline` returns `0` or not. `getline` encounter EOF means `ls` can not produce output.

Comment: I was looking at https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Auto_002dset.html under `ERRNO`. May be I missed a point if they were referring it applies only when used `system()`

Comment: @Inian See my edited version

Comment: Just what I wanted to know! Could you also point me the part of the `awk` source code that you found in the answer. Also quick (off-topic) question, my doesn't my `bash` recognize the `POSIXLY_CORRECT` variable? It seems to behave the same way and sets the exit code as before.

Comment: @Inian How do you set `POSIXLY_CORRECT`. If you copy paste my code above, it should work. If you set POSIXLY_CORRECT in separate command, it won't. If you want to do in separate command, you have to export POSIXLY_CORRECT=1. You can read the `do_close()` in io.c

Comment: @Inian link to source code https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gawk.git/tree/io.c?h=gawk-4.2-stable#n1238

Comment: I had to manually `export` the variable to get the POSIX behavior, but the syntax for locally to the command is not working

Comment: Also I still don't see the behavior, `ERRNO` in `awk`. I don't see it working on `system()` call also `cmd = "ls -lrth /non/existing/path" ; system(cmd); print ENVIRON["ERRNO"]`

Comment: @Inian maybe your gawk version does not honor POSIXLY_CORRECT, you may try `awk --posix`. `ERRNO` variable is set when one of your awk function failed to run. It has nothing to do with `cmd`.

Answer (score 4):

ERRNO will only be set by gawk (GNU awk *only*) if the getline or close fails, but it succeeds in reading the (empty!) output of ls.
That output is empty, because ls gives an error message ("ls: cannot access ...") on the standard error channel, writes nothing to the standard output, and exists with an error code.

With GNU awk you can get the exit status of the command like that:

```
exitstatus=close(cmd)
if (exitstatus) {
    # do something
}
```

If you need the error message of the command, then you haveto redirect its standard error channell to some file, and read that:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
    cmd = "ls -lrth /non/existing/path 2>standard-error.txt"
    while ( ( cmd | getline result ) > 0 ) {
        print result
    }
    es=close(cmd);
    if (es) {
        getline errstring < "standard-error.txt"
        print "exitstatus "es" error message "errstring;
    }
}'
```

Comment: Thanks! I see `512` as the code returned from `ls`. But why is it not throwing `ENOENT` (2) which is the error number corresponding to 'No such file or directory'?

Comment: Can you give  link to document indicates that `close(cmd)` returns the exit code of command? If that's true, then that should be exit status (512), not exit code (2)

Comment: GNU awk: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Close-Files-And-Pipes.html#Close-Files-And-Pipes
The return code is a mess, but 0..255 are exit codes, 256..511 signal codes, 512.. signal codes if a core dump happened.

Comment: @inian: the ls exit code is not an errno, it is just a state code. And on my system i get exit code 2.

Comment: @UweOhse No, I found by looking at GNU awk source code, it's the exit status when GNU awk not in posix mode, see my edited answer.